# Create html report in python

Tags: python-3.8

I have below python function which is working fine but I want to write also an html report which is working also.Below is the problem I am facing

1.It is terminating the script if there is any exception happens.

```
def animal_list():
        animal_name_list = ['lion','Tiger','Dog','Cat']
        f = open('health.html', 'w')
        message = """<html><head><style>
        table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
        </style></head><body>
        <h1>REPORT</h1>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>ANIMALt Name</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        </tr>"""
        for an_name in animal_name_list:
            animalval = checkval(an_name)
            try:
                if animalval == '1':
                message += "<tr><td>{}</td>".format(an_name)
                message += "<td>{}</td>".format("NO")
                else:
                    message += "<tr><td>{}</td>".format(an_name)
                    connection = Connection(an_name)
                    cursor = connection.cursor()
                    message += "<td>{}</td>".format("GOOD")
                    cursor.close()
                    connection.close()
            except Exception as e:
                logging.info(e)
                message += "<td>{}</td></tr>".format(e)
                message += "</table></body></html>"
                f.write(message)
                f.close()
    
    animal_list()
```

I is creating the html page in below format.Not sure what is wrong going on when any exception happens it doesn't go to next element of the list

```
          REPORT

ANIMAL NAME        STATUS
LION               GOOD
DOG                NO
CAT                GOOD
TIGER              <error message>
```

Comment: Could you expand on *"working partially"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is just giving me only Header values  like REPORT and column name(ANIMAL NAME AND STATUS)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a [mre]. Have you looked at the emitted HTML?

Comment: @jonrsharpe nope I didn’t check

Answer (score 0):

Final solution of creating right html

```
def animal_list():
        animal_name_list = ['lion','Tiger','Dog','Cat']
        f = open('health.html', 'w')
        message = """<html><head><style>
        table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
        </style></head><body>
        <h1>REPORT</h1>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>ANIMALt Name</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        </tr>"""
        for an_name in animal_name_list:
            animalval = checkval(an_name)
            try:
                if animalval == '1':
                message += "<tr><td>{}</td>".format(an_name)
                message += "<td>{}</td>".format("NO")
                else:
                message += "<tr><td>{}</td>".format(an_name)
                    connection = Connection(an_name)
                    cursor = connection.cursor()
                message += "<td>{}</td>".format("GOOD")
                    cursor.close()
                    connection.close()
            except Exception as e:
                logging.info(e)
                message += "<td>{}</td></tr>".format(e)
         message += "</table></body></html>"
         f.write(message)
         f.close()
         
    
    animal_list()
```